# What kind of Medicine did Doctor Zoidberg study?

Tags: futurama

He has a Ph.D. and wears a labcoat, but what kind of Medical education did Dr. Zoidberg have?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Zoidberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoidberg) is supposed to be a doctor of medicine, and acts as staff doctor for Planet Express, despite his

> "*woeful understanding of human physiology and allusions to his
>   questionable credentials.*"

He claims to be an "M".D. (see below),but states in [A Clone of My Own](https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:A_Clone_of_My_Own) that he (ahem) misplaced his medical qualifications

> **Cubert:** *As long as I'm going to be in charge here, let me examine my so-called "crew", if it can so be called. First of all, Dr.
>   Zoidberg, do you even have a medical degree?*
>
> **Zoidberg:** *I lost it ... in a volcano.*

However, he later states in "[The Duh-Vinci Code](https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:The_Duh-Vinci_Code)" that his doctorate isn't in medicine at all

> **Zoidberg:** *Maybe da Vinci painted over something else. It's called a pentimento.*
>
> **Farnsworth:** *That's true, Dr. Zoidberg. How did you know that?*
>
> **Zoidberg:** *My doctorate is in Art History.*

---

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding in some quotes

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the episode ["The Duh-Vinci Code"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Duh-Vinci_Code), Zoidberg has his doctorate in art history.